# using new[] with lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, c#-6.0

```
protected override IEnumerable<string> Attributes => new []
{
  IntercationAttributes.State
};
```

Can somebody explain me what is happening here. Why we have new[] with lambda expression. I have seen it for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an anonymous method (a.k.a. lambda expression) but instead a way to write computed properties in a more concise manner. It's exactly equivalent to

```
protected override IEnumerable<string> Attributes {
  get { return new [] { IntercationAttributes.State };
}
```

As you can see, a read-only property of the form

```
<property> { get { return <expression>; } }
```

can be written as

```
<property> => <expression>;
```

in C# 6, reducing the syntax around the declaration a bit.

Comment: cool thanks a lot for your explantion